# Sorting a query result using nested clauses

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm using this database table for my Laravel app:

```
| id | description | status   | timestamp  |
|----|-------------|----------|------------|
| 1  | Lorem ipsum | pending  | 2019-08-01 |
| 2  | Lorem ipsum | approved | 2019-08-01 |
| 3  | Lorem ipsum | pending  | 2019-08-01 |
| 4  | Lorem ipsum | approved | 2019-08-01 |
| 5  | Lorem ipsum | review   | 2019-08-01 |
| 6  | Lorem ipsum | review   | 2019-08-01 |
| 7  | Lorem ipsum | closed   | 2019-08-01 |
| 8  | Lorem ipsum | pending  | 2019-08-01 |
| 9  | Lorem ipsum | approved | 2019-08-01 |
...
```

The desired ordering logic for this table is:

```
pending > review > approved > closed
```

and then after, each subgroup must be ordered by

```
id, DESC
```

So the desired result should be:

```
| id | description | status   | timestamp  |
|----|-------------|----------|------------|
| 8  | Lorem ipsum | pending  | 2019-08-01 |
| 3  | Lorem ipsum | pending  | 2019-08-01 |
| 1  | Lorem ipsum | pending  | 2019-08-01 |
| 6  | Lorem ipsum | review   | 2019-08-01 |
| 5  | Lorem ipsum | review   | 2019-08-01 |
| 9  | Lorem ipsum | approved | 2019-08-01 |
| 4  | Lorem ipsum | approved | 2019-08-01 |
| 2  | Lorem ipsum | approved | 2019-08-01 |
| 7  | Lorem ipsum | closed   | 2019-08-01 |
...
```

I tried to use this eloquent query:

```
$posts = Post::orderByRaw( "FIELD(status, 'pending', 'review', 'approved', 'closed')" )
         ->groupBy('id')
         ->paginate(5)
         ->toJson();
```

However, the ID order is ascending:

```
| id | description | status   | timestamp  |
|----|-------------|----------|------------|
| 1  | Lorem ipsum | pending  | 2019-08-01 |
| 3  | Lorem ipsum | pending  | 2019-08-01 |
| 8  | Lorem ipsum | pending  | 2019-08-01 |
| 5  | Lorem ipsum | review   | 2019-08-01 |
| 6  | Lorem ipsum | review   | 2019-08-01 |
| 2  | Lorem ipsum | approved | 2019-08-01 |
| 4  | Lorem ipsum | approved | 2019-08-01 |
| 9  | Lorem ipsum | approved | 2019-08-01 |
| 7  | Lorem ipsum | closed   | 2019-08-01 |
...
```

I can't figure out how to order the rows with the greater id first INSIDE each sub-result grouped by statuses.

Comment: Grouping by ID never makes any sense as they are UNIQUE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `groupBy()` on the ID instead of `orderBy()`. You can either add `, id DESC` in your `orderByRaw()` method, or add a `orderBy('id', 'desc')` in place of the `groupBy()` method.

Using a `groupBy('id')` in this case makes little sense, as its unique.

```php
$posts = Post::orderByRaw( "FIELD(status, 'pending', 'review', 'approved', 'closed')" )
             ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
             ->paginate(5)
             ->toJson();
```